# Lag while playing youtube videos at 1080p

Tags: nvidia, firefox, video, youtube

I'm running linux lite based on Ubuntu 16.04 in my Sony laptop with :-
2 GHZ Core 2 Duo T2500, 
2gb Ram,
Nvidia Geforce 7400Go.

1080p Videos runs smoothly without any problem in VLC player (Downloaded Videos). But in Youtube, it is playing only audio and the video is stuck.. I'm using Mozilla Firefox 77.0.1 as my default browser..

I've tried installing Adobe flashplayer V32.0.0.371 but it hasn't changed anything in this regard.. Is it the problem with cpu?? Please help

Comment: My guess would be insufficient memory. Run a command in terminal like free -m to see how much available memory you have. Also you can use System Monitor and sort by memory to see who is using what. Flash Player isn't needed for Youtube anymore.

Comment: I have 2gb of ram and when Youtube is open, only like 30%-40% of Ram is used. The problem is not with the memory i feel... @user3169 Thanks for the reply mahn.. Any other suggestions?? Please Help..

Comment: Well I don't know "linux lite" (Lubuntu or ?). As I said a guess. What do you get from https://www.youtube.com/html5 ? Flash plugin should be disabled in case it's causing problems.

Comment: if you disable all plugins in firefox does the playback change at all? (i have had problems with some youtube videos and disabeling the plugin ublock orgin did help me).2 gig ram is in the low end of memory needed to run ubuntu so if possible install more ram like 4 gigs or more.

Answer (score 0):

Flash player in 2020 on Firefox 77 is an anomaly. Unless you manually enabled Flash, YouTube should be serving videos via HTML5.

A few good places to start your troubleshooting:

- Enable/disable hardware acceleration in Firefox options
- Update your graphics driver, on install the proprietary Nvidia one
- Update/install modern video/audio codecs

What does [this YouTube page](https://www.youtube.com/supported_browsers) display for you?